# Understanding the formula for the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

The Vandermonde matrix has an inverse given by the following formula.

[image: Vandermonde Inverse]

I don't understand what the following notation means.

$$
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq m_1 < \cdots < m_{n-j}\leq n}\\ \quad m_1,\dots,m_{n-j} \neq i} x_{m_1} \cdots x_{m_{n-j}}.
$$

Any help accompanied by an example would be great.

Comment: Why don't you make your own example to see how it works, say for size $4 \times 4$? [Like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+%7B%7B1%2Cx%2Cx%5E2%2Cx%5E3%7D%2C%7B1%2Cy%2Cy%5E2%2Cy%5E3%7D%2C%7B1%2Cz%2Cz%5E2%2Cz%5E3%7D%2C%7B1%2Cw%2Cw%5E2%2Cw%5E3%7D%7D), with the help of WA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, I will denote
$$
S_{ij} = \sum_{\substack{1 \leq m_1 < \cdots < m_{n-j}\leq n}\\ \quad m_1,\dots,m_{n-j} \neq i} x_{m_1} \cdots x_{m_{n-j}}.
$$
In words, we could write that $S_{ij}$ is the sum of all terms of the form $x_{m_1}\cdots x_{m_{n-j}}$ such that $m_1,\dots,m_{n-j}$ is an increasing tuple of ($n-j$) integers between $1$ and $n$, all of which are not equal to $i$.

As an example, take $n = 5, i = 2, j = 2$. Here is a list of every increasing tuple of $n-j = 3$ integers between $1$ and $n = 5$, where none of the integers are equal to $i = 2$.
$$
1,3,4;\\
1,3,5;\\
1,4,5;\\
3,4,5.
$$
Thus, for $n = 5$, we have
$$
S_{22} = x_1x_3x_4 + x_1x_3x_5 + x_1x_4x_5 + x_3x_4x_5.
$$
As a second example, take $n = 5, i=2, j=3$. Here is a list of every increasing tuple of $n-j = 2$ integers between $1$ and $n = 5$, where none of the integers are equal to $i = 2$.
$$
1,3;\\
1,4;\\
1,5;\\
3,4;\\
3,5;\\
4,5.\\
$$
Thus, for $n = 5$, we have
$$
S_{23} = x_1x_3 + x_1x_4 + x_1x_5 + x_3x_4 + x_3x_5 + x_4x_5.
$$